# Blackberry 10 Development

Tags: blackberry-10

I am developing an application in Blackberry 10. I have installed QNXMomentics for development, and Dev alpha Simulator for debugging. For running application in QNX need to specify the IP Addess from device or simulator. But on my simulator it does not showing the menu, Only the welcome screen is showing in the simulator , What the problem here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In context of your problem, Richard gives you idea about how to connect you **simulator** or **device** to your IDE you can find out one more option there is **AUTO DISCOVER**.

On startup of your loading your simulator on VM player their are two option for selecting screen type:

1. BB10DevAlfaKeyboard
2. BB10DevAlfaKeyboardSafe

Try 2nd option.
(*This setting for simulator debug only)

Your blackberry simulator device get stuck on welcome screen, I think this happens because of your **PC** hardware configuration little bit low, for first time it will take time
you have to wait till you didn't get **HOME SCREEN** of your **BB Os 10** on your simulator.

Answer (score 3):

On the simulator home screen, at the top, near the time you should see an icon that looks like a person with a gear inside. Selecting that icon will show you the IP addresses assigned to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Or Run->Debug configuration...->Add new target->auto discover